# Picking a random word with an specific number of letters in bash

Tags: bash, random, cpu-word, letters

I need to pick a random word with `n` letters, `n` will be the parameter.

I have this:

```
#!bin/bash
shuf -n1 /usr/share/dict/words
```

So I know how to pick a random word but not with a specific number of letters.

Comment: Does it have to be a valid word? Else you could cut too long words. Why not keep picking, until the size fits?

Comment: yes, it will must be a valid word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for words with 3 characters :

```
grep '^.\{3\}$' /usr/share/dict/words | shuf -n1
```

#### If you need a variable :

```
num=3
grep "^.\{$num\}\$"
```

### Explanations of the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) :

- `^` : start *anchor* of line
- `.` : any character
- `\{3\}` : *quantifier* of the last character
- `$` : end of line *anchor*

Comment: It works, thank you a lot, can you explain me what it means '^.{3}$'  if it's not too much trouble. thanks a lot man you are great!

Comment: I had decomposed the command for you if you refresh the page (in case you don't). This is a _regex_ to match words with 3 characters